# Go ListenAndServeTLS

Tags: ssl, go

Im currently trying to use this function for my http server. I already have the cert.pem and the private.key but I am getting this error

> crypto/tls: failed to parse private key

No idea what is wrong. This is the correct key because any other key will just throw

> private key does not match public key

They are both on the same folder

Since I am not sure how risky is to expose the key. It starts with this

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,D353D2D8ACDA5320
....
---END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The code I am using

```
err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":80", "mycert.pem", "private.key", router)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Comment: share the code you load and parse with

Comment: I believe the issue is that your private key is encrypted with a password. I think you'll need to use an unencrypted PEM.

Comment: ^This fixed the error. But now my browser wont recognize the cert at all? ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR maybe this belongs to a different question tho.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say open a new question for that.

Comment: @AlvaroCarvajalNakosmai SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR typically means there's an issue with the handshake, or your certificate has an error. Can you share the certificate? (it's OK to share the cert; just not the key)